# Weaviate conditional filter throws "... invalid search term, only stopwords provided"

Tags: weaviate

I have a `Profile` class with a property `industry` with the following possible values:

- Marketing
- Engineering
- IT
- Education

everything is almost OK not until I tried filtering the "IT" industry value (other options above work fine). Below is my GraphQL query:

```
echo '{
  "query": "{
      Get {
        Profile (
          where: {
            path: [\"industry\"],
            operator: Equal,
            valueText: \"IT\"
          }
        ){
          source_id
          name
          industry
          _additional {
              id
          }
      }
    }
  }"
}' | curl \
    -X POST \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer CHANGE_ME_API_KEY" \
    -d @- \
    http://localhost:8890/v1/graphql | python -m json.tool
```

and below is the error when filtering for "IT" industry:

```
{
    "data": {
        "Get": {
            "Profile": null
        }
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "locations": [
                {
                    "column": 21,
                    "line": 1
                }
            ],
            "message": "explorer: list class: search: object search at index profile: local shard object search profile_GWO2vDh4LCcU: invalid search term, only stopwords provided. Stopwords can be configured in class.invertedIndexConfig.stopwords",
            "path": [
                "Get",
                "Profile"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, given that it might be because the "IT" is part of stopwords in English language -> "it" then it could be the issue so I tried updating the class configuration and now here is what we have:

[image]

But still, I got the same error regarding stopwords so I am now a bit confused and would appreciate some help. Are we missing something in our configuration?